# Conditionally add hide-xs attribute

Tags: angular-material

In an ng-repeat I want to add a `hide-xs` attribute on an element based on the current scope.
How can I do that?

I basically want to do something like (this obviously don't work):

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" hide-xs="{{ item.showAlways ? 'false' : 'true' }}">
    <a href="" ng-click="item.action()">{{item.title}}</a>
</li>
```

**Edit**

I ended up doing this (as suggested by *DieuNQ*) but if anybody know how to do it using directive and not class I would take it

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'hide-xs': !item.showAlways }}">
    <a href="" ng-click="item.action()">{{item.title}}</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hide-xs` not works like that (it does not depend on true or false). It just add class to your `tag`. Try this:

In your html:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-model="item.showAlways" ng-class="someClass">
    ...
</li>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.item.showAlways ? $scope.someClass == '' : $scope.someClass == 'hide-xs';
```

Comment: I did an easier ng-class="{ 'hide-xs': item.showAlways }" and it works fine. Using directive is better than using class IMHO but it works :)